# ldd equivalent on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ldd, readelf

I have a libTest.so that does not load on some devices. logcat is absolutely useless.
Using `arm-linux-androideabi-readelf.exe -d libTest.so` I was able to see all required libs that libTest.so needs. I pulled them all in, into the same folder on my local PC.

How can I find out which symbols is missing and in which library? I have only standard set of tools from the NDK (nm, readelf, objdump etc). Which tool and how can I use so that it parses my  libTest.so and all dependent libs as well and tells me which symbol prevents my lib from loading on the target device.

Comment: <NDK_DIR>/toolchains/llvm/prebuild/<HOST_OS>/bin/<ARCH>-strings | grep ^lib | grep so

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to android developers. My feature request was implemented :)
Now we have [ndk-depends](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/426f4ee8a8c3be97122c1a6bf5f58dbd9486bbc9/docs/text/NDK-DEPENDS.text), a tool that allows to troubleshoot dependencies.

Edit: it doesn't do full symbol resolution though. E.g. if you build against Android-14 and try to use methods that didn't exist in old Androids, then this tool won't list missing symbols. This part was left as a TODO in ndk-depends.

Comment: unfortunately ndk-depends was removed in ndk r19: https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r19#announcements

Answer (score 22):

If you don't have the NDK try doing:

```
readelf --dynamic filename | grep NEEDED
```

to display the dynamic libraries for an elf binary.

Answer (score 6):

At Android terminal try this:
`strings /path/to/your/file | grep ^lib`
Found here: 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2737126&page=5

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$ /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --list filename
```

This is because ldd is just a shell script that works like a wrapper around the dynamic loader. The name of the dynamic loader, i.e., ld-{version}.so might differ.

Comment: Android appears to use `/system/bin/linker` and not `/lib/ld-linux.so` . Anyhow I can't get linker to output anything

Comment: I just get `Segmentation fault` when invoking `/system/bin/linker` directly, no matter what arguments I use!